# SQL Server stored procedure with multiple table insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and I am writing a stored procedure to insert into many tables with foreign keys.

I am getting two errors:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure insertintoorders, Line 163
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Customers__Addre__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in database "FlowerCompany", table "dbo.Addresses", column 'AddressID'.
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure insertintoorders, Line 178
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Orders__Customer__1FCDBCEB". The conflict occurred in database "FlowerCompany", table "dbo.Customers", column 'CustomerID'.

Here is my stored procedure and my testing execution of it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertintoorders
    @Street varchar(50), 
    @City varchar(30), 
    @State varchar(2), 
    @Zip varchar(9),
    @Phone varchar(10),
    @FlowerName varchar(50), 
    @FirstName varchar(40),
    @LastName varchar(40),
    @OrderStatus varchar(12),
    @DeliverDate date,
    @OrderMessage varchar(100), 
    @OrderDate date, 
    @Vase bit, 
    @OrderCost decimal(6,2)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @flower int;

    SELECT @flower = Arr.FlowerID
    FROM Arrangements Arr
    WHERE FlowerName = @FlowerName

    DECLARE @AddID int;
    SELECT @AddID = coalesce((SELECT MAX(AddressID) + 1 FROM Addresses), 1)

    DECLARE @PhoneID int;
    SELECT @PhoneID = coalesce((SELECT MAX(PhoneID) + 1 FROM Phone), 1)

    DECLARE @CustID int;
    SELECT @CustID = coalesce((SELECT MAX(CustomerID) + 1 FROM Customers), 1)

    DECLARE @Del int;
    SELECT @Del = coalesce((SELECT MAX(DeliveryID) + 1 FROM Delivery), 1)

    DECLARE @Ords int;
    SELECT @Ords = coalesce((select max(StatusID) + 1 from OrderStatus), 1)

    DECLARE @Ord int;
    SELECT @Ord = coalesce((select max(OrderID) + 1 from Orders), 1)

    INSERT INTO Addresses (Street, City, States, Zip)
    VALUES (@Street, @City, @State, @Zip)

    SET @AddId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Phone (Phone)
    VALUES (@Phone)

    SET @PhoneID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Customers (AddressID, PhoneID, FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @FirstName, @LastName)

    SET @CustID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Delivery (DeliverDate)
    VALUES (@DeliverDate)

    SET @Del = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO OrderStatus (OrderStatus)
    VALUES (@OrderStatus)

    SET @Ords = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Orders ([CustomerID], [FlowerID], [StatusID],[DeliveryID], OrderMessage, OrderDate, OrderCost, Vase)
    VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @flower, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @OrderMessage, @OrderDate, @OrderCost, @Vase)

    SET @Ord = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO

EXEC insertintoorders @Street = '555 LANE', @City='Somewhere', @State = 'XX', @Zip = '99999', @Phone = '1234567896', @FlowerName = 'The Flower of Love', @FirstName = 'George', 
@LastName = 'Fish', @DeliverDate = '10/10/2016', @OrderStatus = 'Completed', @OrderMessage = 'Fishy flowers', @OrderDate = '03/03/2016', @OrderCost = '200', @Vase = '1'
```

Although I had read the errors, I am not understanding how to fix them or why they are there.

Comment: So your tables already have PK on IDENTITY columns, but you likely don't trust this work to stupid server and do all the work yourself? Like hard ways?

Comment: Can you show the scripts for the foreign keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `IDENTITY_INSERT` and inserting your own values for PhoneId and AddressId.  `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is always the last value inserted into an identity column, so after you insert into phone it will return PhoneId and never AddId.

Option 1: Use the values you have.  This is a bad idea because if you do two adds at the same time, you might get conflicts

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers ON
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID,AddressID,PhoneID,FirstName,LastName)
VALUES (@CustID, @AddId, @PhoneId ,@FirstName, @LastName)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers OFF
```

Option 2: Just let the system set the identity values and get them after each insert, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO Addresses (Street, City, States, Zip)
VALUES (@Street,@City,@State,@Zip)
SET @AddId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: I changed things to option 2 and I am getting the same error

Comment: remove all your `select max+1` part totally

Comment: Fill in each variable with SCOPE_IDENTITY value right after appropriate insert statement. Just like @Jason demonstrated with example for `Addresses`.